# How to build an html form without using apex:form on the page?

Tags: apex, html, form

I have an html `<form>` I would like to use to trigger an apex function without using any `<apex:form>` on the page. Is that possible? If so how?

Code sample:

Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="SomeObj__c" extensions="myProcessor">
   <form action="send" method="post">
      <!-- some fields with values to send over -->
   </form> 
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class myProcessor {

    public myProcessor(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    }

    public PageReference send() {
        // processing
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to not use `apex:form`?

Comment: On reason is that the `apex:form` with `forceSSL="true"` cannot have its action url processed by a URL Rewriter class. I would expect to control the behavior using an HTML form instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking you'll need to use Javascript Remoting since `apex:actionFunction` has to be in an `apex:form`.  However, since it uses asynchronous ajax, you'll need to prevent submitting the form until the callback function:

New Controller method:

```
@remoteMethod
public static string send()
{
    return '';
}
```

Visualforce:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doSubmit(form)
    {
        myProcessor.send(function(result, event){
                form.target = result;
                form.submit();
        });
        return !!form.target; //Prevent the first submit
    }
</script>
<form action="send" method="post" onsubmit="return doSubmit(this);">
  <!-- some fields with values to send over -->
</form>
```

Comment: That's a fair solution indeed

Comment: @Julio As an aside, if you are using a standard html element like a button to submit the form, you could have its onclick function always return false and call the remoting function above, so you wouldn't need the weird `return !!form.target` line.